# How to synchronize merge subscription in Sql Compact DB (on a Mobile device emulator)

Tags: mobile, sql-server-ce, replication

Using SQL ManagementStudio 2008 I created SQL 3.5 Compact DB (TestCompact.sdf) and I have created subscription to existing Publication. Using SQL Management Studio it is working. I have transfered TestCompact.sdf to Windows Mobile 5 emulator device and with QueryAnalyzer for Mobile I could query existing tables in TestCompact.sdf. I don't know how to start replication synchronization on that mobile device. Do I need to write some C# code or it is possible do it more simple?

EDIT: (Added after reply on my question)
Maybe it will be useful for someone what C# code did the job for me:
(Using SQL Management Studio - Properties on existing subscription for my Compact DB) I read what are values for a replObj properties)

```
private void btnSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection sqlCeConn = null;
        SqlCeReplication replObj = new SqlCeReplication();
        string connString = @"data source=\My Documents\TestReplicationCompactDB.sdf;Password=bero";
        replObj.InternetUrl = @"http://192.168.99.99/VirtualDirectoryForCompactDBReplication/sqlcesa35.dll";;
        replObj.PublisherDatabase =  "TestReplicationDB";
        replObj.PublisherSecurityMode = SecurityType.NTAuthentication;;
        replObj.Publisher = @"DBTESTSRV\SQL2008";
        replObj.Publication = "TestReplication2";
        replObj.Subscriber = "TestReplication";
        replObj.SubscriberConnectionString = @"data source=\My Documents\TestReplicationCompactDB.sdf;Password=bero";
        replObj.InternetLogin = @"ares\intor";
        replObj.InternetPassword = "intor";
        try
        {
            sqlCeConn = new SqlCeConnection(connString);
            sqlCeConn.Open();
            replObj.Synchronize();
            sqlCeConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            if (sqlCeConn != null && sqlCeConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                sqlCeConn.Close();
            return;
        }
        string countPublisherChanges = replObj.PublisherChanges.ToString();
        string countSubScriberChanges = replObj.SubscriberChanges.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Finished with {0} subscriber changes and with {1} publisher changes", countSubScriberChanges, countPublisherChanges));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write "some" C# code, at the end of the Wizard in SSMS you get some sample code.